# In crypto exchange website, is it possible for the sell price of a coin to go higher than the buy price?

Tags: cryptocurrency

I am using a website to buy/sell crypto currency on instant basis. I don't know how the buy and sell price is calculated. Although the question might sound stupid but out of curiosity, is it possible for the sell price to go higher than the buy price by any chance?

Edit: It's not exactly bid and ask. For example, in CoinDCX, there is an insta feature where users can buy or sell coins instantly without bidding or asking. I haven't been into share trading so I was assuming this feature would be present there as well. Guess it's not.

Comment: are you talking about the bid and ask ?

Comment: If the price is highly volatile, computer lag and latency *might* cause the bid and ask prices to get out of sync like that.

Comment: It's not exactly bid and ask. For example, CoinDCX has an insta buy/sell feature where they display the buy and sell price for a coin. And users can instant buy or sell there without doing bid/ask.

Answer (score 3):

Not unless the exchange does something unusual with fees. If someone was willing to buy at a price equal to or greater than someone else was willing to sell at a properly-functioning exchange, they will have already made a trade with each other. What would they be waiting for?

Comment: Answer assumes that anything relating to cryptocurrency is properly-functioning...

Comment: @RonJohn No major public blockchain has had downtime in more than a year now. Most large centralized services can't say that.

Comment: They've got to be doing *something* wrong for wallets to keep getting stolen.

Comment: @RonJohn I'm not sure who the "they" is referring to there. Mostly what I see is people falling for scams promoted on social media platforms that do absolutely nothing about it and, in some cases, adopt policies that actually encourage it.

Comment: @RonJohn they're called wallets because the best practices are similar. a best practice with a physical wallet is not to keep it in your back pocket because it can get stolen. That's not an issue with fiat or the ID system or credit cards in that wallet, the same is true for cryptocurrency. Follow the best practices and neither your wallet or your funds will get stolen.

Comment: @CQM you only put your wallet in your front pocket all the time if #1 you're paranoid, or #2 you live someplace crawling with pickpockets.

Comment: @RonJohn the point being that the best practice works in both kinds of areas and if you ignore the best practice you wouldn't deflect blame towards the technology, you would blame the criminal and yourself. thanks for making my point.

Comment: @CQM I've seen too many sites get millions of $ worth of Btc stolen due to sysadmin incompetence.  Remember MtGox?  It's incompetence is certainly not rare.

Comment: @RonJohn maybe you should familiarize yourself with the best practices before responding, you keep going down a laundry list of things you think are rebuttals to validate your pre-existing conclusion about a non-existing inherent flaw in the technology, not seeming to realize that you keep validating the purpose of best practices which simply weren't followed. During Mt Gox's operation many people were pointing out all the ways that the users and  the sysadmins were breaking the best practices and the perils of that.

Comment: @RonJohn I realize now that saying "use best practices" might be too ambiguous for you at this point in time, here are links https://medium.com/coinfalcon/your-guide-to-crypto-wallet-best-practices-in-2020-24fb85a4d9c1 https://ssi-ambassador.medium.com/best-practices-of-using-cryptocurrencies-dos-and-don-ts-c983724e3d47 feel free to find a source you recognize and respect, it should say many of the same things. These were the same best practices 10 years ago and they worked then and work now, the only difference is that they are easier and cheaper to do now and that will be the general trend.

Comment: @CQM why did you jump to the conclusion that I said, "inherent flaw in the technology"?  Because I didn't.  It's all about sloppy/lazy/incompetent/greedy people running sites they have no business running.  Like I said... "Remember MtGox?"

Comment: @RonJohn I see now that you were talking about the centralized services. Had to re-read the conversation and how you clarified. Wasn't clear the whole time, but alright.